# Defining header response not working in hiawatha and php

Tags: php, http-headers, phped, hiawatha

I have a local server and a remote server. On the local server what I'm trying to do works, but the remote server which is hiawatha doesn't.

I'm trying to set a not found header and then respond with the login page. I'm using the following code to do that

```
if($e === "ErrorSessionExpired")
        {

            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
            $output = $this->smarty->fetch("login.tpl");
            echo $output;
            exit();
        }
```

As I said this works fine on the developing machine, which uses the embedded server of PhpED

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message that you could share?

Comment: Hiawatha has since been updated to work with the HTTP-style of header-setting. Previously it would only accept the CGI style, as per ADW's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

Comment: To add to this, which seems correct, I'd actually send a 403 since he's issuing a auth challenge. `header("Status: 403 Authorization Required");`